# Logo not appearing in nav bar / Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building a website and can't work out why my logo is not appearing. I added a h1 tag within the same div, which displays and also displays the logo underneath however once I delete the h1 tag the logo disappears as well? I added it to a demo here http://dev.samuelrhys.com/productwave/

Thanks,

```
<div id="topbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="social-links">
      <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="logo float-left">
    <h1 class="text-light"><a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><span>Rapidsss</span></a></h1>
    <a href="#header" class="scrollto"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
  </div>

  <nav class="main-nav float-right d-none d-lg-block">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#footer">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .main-nav -->

</div>
```

Comment: If you use an svg image, better use <svg>, I had problems with disappearing svg <img>. <svg> solved the problem.

Comment: give us working example of it

Comment: Too many missing details to help you here - most important being the CSS.. Without it all I can say is try giving the `img` tag a width and height and see if it helps.

Comment: I suspect the path being wrong. Tested with jsfiddle and an http link and the image was shown correctly.

Comment: I tried removing h1 but the svg logo is [still there](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/gyEzjb)

Comment: Hi I put the demo on here http://dev.samuelrhys.com/productwave/, I tried adding the <svg> but that didn't seem to work? Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're using SVG as your logo image. Vector images do not have intrinsic height or width. So, you need to give either desired height OR width to IMG tag and let other dimension workout by browser (`auto`).

HTML

```
<img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="img-fluid">
```

CSS

```
.img-fluid {
      width: 150px;
      height: auto; //which is default, you don't need to mention that unless you want to override.
}
```